# Disable iptables permanently in CentOS

Tags: centos, firewall, iptables

I used the following commands
`service iptables save`
`service iptables stop`
`chkconfig iptables off`

But after sometime, when I run the command `service iptables status`, 
I shows me a list of rules.

How to disable `iptables` permanently?

Comment: What do you see after running `service iptables status` just after `service iptables stop`? What message do  you see after issuing `service iptables stop`?

Comment: After issuing `service iptables stop`, I get  
`iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: mangle filter na[  OK  ]`  
`iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]`  
`iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]`  
And after this, when I run  `service iptables status`, I get  
`iptables: Firewall is not running.`

Answer (score 0):

you can try it .

iptables -F .

flush all rules.

Comment: and you have to run this command after every reboot as to me everything goes back as default as ftp + webmin are blocked on each reboot...